# Prohibido (403) Verificación CSRF fallida. Petición abortada. ADMIN DE DJANGO

Tags: python, django

Lamentablemente busque por todos lados y no encuentro solucion a mi problema, por eso recurro a la gran comunidad de stackoverflow

estoy intentando hacer deploy con PAGEKITE y todo funciona bien la app se puede ver bien, hasta el momento de querer abrir el administrador , me tira error 403 - CSRF fallida

Se que es un problema muy probablemente de cookies pero nose como generarlas

Estoy usando django 2.2.6 y python 3.9

Tambien intente usar otro navegador pero cualquier navegador me tira el error
Probe borrar todas las cookies pero tampoco funciono
probe CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE en True y tampoco me funciono

aclaro que no modifique el ADMIN, esta el nativo de django

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]